# JPA Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to connect to aws using spring boot. However I cannot start my application. Here is the error message:

> -[12:03 AM, 10/19/2017] :Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier:mytest-dbinstance}':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.services.rds.model.AmazonRDSException: The security
>   token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status
>   Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID:
>   59857b7b-b49b-11e7-b732-9310e73fdbaf)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav…
>   Read more
>       [12:13 AM, 10/19/2017] +1 (408) 209-8367: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6987

My pom.xml has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>AwsFileUpload</name>
<description>File management using AWS services</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-rds -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.11.106</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-jdbc -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>




<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->enter code here
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>3.3.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is right there in the Stack

```
 Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier:mytest-dbinstance}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.rds.model.AmazonRDSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 59857b7b-b49b-11e7-b732-9310e73fdbaf) at
```

Your AWS Creds/Request is invalid.